# Use the form of the definition of the integral to evaluate the integral (4-2x)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Use the form of the definition of the integral to evaluate the integral.

$$a=2, b=5, (4-2x)dx$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(4-2x)\Delta x$$

$$\Delta x = \frac{3}{n}$$
$$x_i=2+i\frac{3}n$$

$$(f(2+1\frac{3}n)+f(2+2\frac{3}n)+f(2+3\frac{3}n))\frac3n$$

The answer is -9, but with only using the definition of the interval without n given how can I find a numeric answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right ingredients but seem to be having trouble putting them together.

By definition,
\begin{align*}
\int_2^5(4-2x)\,dx
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left\{4-2\cdot\left(2+k\cdot\frac{3}{n}\right)\right\}\frac{3}{n} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left\{\frac{12}{n}-\frac{12}{n}-k\cdot\frac{18}{n^2}\right\} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot\frac{-18}{n^2} \\
&= -\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{18}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^nk \\
&= -\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{18}{n^2}\frac{n\cdot(n+1)}{2} \\
&= -9\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+n}{n^2} \\
&= -9
\end{align*}
Here we have utilized the formula
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n\cdot(n+1)}{2}
$$